# How can I determine if a point is on a line between two other points in 3d in Lua (or other language)?

Tags: math, vector, lua, 3d

I have a line between two points a and b (3d vectors) and a third point p (from scalar projection).

I want to determine if the third point p is on the line between a and b or not between them.

What is the most efficient algorithm for the LuaJIT? Other languages would be fine too, but efficiency is important

Thanks to numberZero I got this code and it seems to work

```
function vec3d:is_between(a, b)
    local ab = b - a
    local ap = self - a
    local lp = ap:len()
    local lb = ab:len()
    local dot = ap:dot(ab) / (lp * lb)
    return lp < lb and dot > 0.95
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the points lie on a single line, you may just calculate a dot product, and if *0 ≤ 〈AB, AP〉 ≤ 〈AB, AB〉*, then *P* is between *A* and *B*. But note that if *P* is not exactly on the line, this method may give strange results. But it should be the fastest.

You may also want to calculate 2 values, distance from *P* to *AB* and (orthogonal) projection of *AP* onto *AB*. The latter is *AP_AB = 〈AP, AB〉 / 〈AB, AB〉* (in *AB* units, so that if *AP* and *AB* are collinear, *AP = AB * AP_AB*), and the former is *ρ(P, AB) = ρ(AP, AB * AP_AB) = |AP - AB * AP_AB|*. So, if the *ρ(P, AB)* is small, you decide that if *0 ≤ AP_AB ≤ 1*, then *P* is between *A* and *B*

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the three points are collinear, you could compute the vector **AP** from **a** to **p** and the vector **AB** from **a** to **b**.  If **p** is between **a** and **b**, then the [dot product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotProduct.html) of **AP** and **AB** will equal 1 (i.e. the vectors point in the same direction) and the [vector magnitude](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorMagnitude.html) of **AP** will be less than that of **AB**.

If you don't know whether the points are **collinear**, it's easy to check.  You can determine the collinearity of three points  **x**<sub>i</sub> =
 (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, z<sub>i</sub>) for *i* = 1, 2, 3 by implementing a test on the ratio of distances:

> x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub> : y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub> : z<sub>2</sub> -
>    z<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>3</sub> - x<sub>1</sub> : y<sub>3</sub> -
>    y<sub>1</sub> : z<sub>3</sub> - z<sub>1</sub>.

as [explained in this Wolfram Mathworld article on Collinearity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html).  From the same article, an even easier condition

> is obtained by noting that the area of a triangle determined by three points will be zero iff they are collinear (including the degenerate cases of two or all three points being concurrent), i.e....in expanded form
>
> x<sub>1</sub>( y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>3</sub> ) + x<sub>2</sub>( y<sub>3</sub> -
>    y<sub>1</sub>) + x<sub>3</sub>( y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub> ) = 0.

Comment: I know that all three points are on the same line. I need to know if point p is between a and b or outside. Or maybe I don't understand your answer

Comment: How do I calculate AP and AB? 

AP = p - a and AB = b - a?

Comment: Exactly. So AP_x = p_x - a_x etc.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Maybe I can implement this directly to my scalar projection function. Then I only need to do the math once and I return a point and a boolean

Comment: Happy to help. If this has answered your question, @burli, please "accept" the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it's working. Need more testing, but looks good. Will accept if I'm sure. Thanks